# Runtime error in online assessment compiler

Tags: python

I'm currently using a platform, Hacker-Trial to test run out the code for a problem, Two-Sum. Using a hash-map, the algorithm goes something like this:

```
prevMap = {} # val -> index
    
    for i, n in enumerate(nums):
        diff = target - n
        if diff in prevMap:
            return [prevMap[diff], i]
        prevMap[n] = i
```

However, the platform is giving me a runtime error. I'm not sure what's causing the reason, but do I define something in the main?

```
def main(target:int, nums:List[int]):
prevMap = {} # val -> index
    
    for i, n in enumerate(nums):
        diff = target - n
        if diff in prevMap:
            return [prevMap[diff], i]
        prevMap[n] = i
```

main()

Despite defining the variables I will be using in the main function, the runtime errors still happens to me.

Attached is the interface given to me:

[HackerTrial Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQTNO.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you submit the code with the same indentation as you've shown, then it might crash because you've got indentation wrong

Comment: I've corrected the indentation and the same error occurs unfortunately

Comment: Do you include `main()` in your code? It should be called with two parameters